# Replacing "\" in openrefine

Tags: openrefine

it seems to me that the expression

```
value.replace("\", "")
```

doesn't work. It doesn't also if there are other characters with \, like:

```
value.replace("\xnes", "")
```

I've got some data with those and I need to erase it. Why is it behaving like this?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to replace \ literally, you need to type \\. \ is used to escape characters in strings in many programming languages.

Comment: So simple and yet so hard to think about (for me)

Comment: It's just something you'll need to come across once, I think it's something everyone runs into when they first start out

Comment: A bit more explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52456548/special-characters-in-replace-function).